# Current Density in conductor in DC Mode

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, voltage, maxwell-equations

I was trying to calculate the current density in a conductor subject to DC voltage but I come to an absurdity. I took a circular copper conductor.

[Situation scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPR0n.jpg)

I have considered the Drude Model : $ j = E\sigma $.

We have a current so we have a magnetic field in the conductor :
$$ B(r) = \frac{\mu_0 }{r} \int_{0}^{r}\sigma E(r)r  .dr $$
It seems to be the equivalent of $ B = \frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi r}$ for inside the conductor.
I have assumed that the electric field was pretty uniform in the conductor so we have :
$$ B(r) = \mu_0 \sigma E r $$
Following the definition of $j = ne v $ we have $v=\frac{j}{ne}$ (ie. $v=\frac{\sigma E}{ne}$).

So now if we applies Lorentz Law to the flow of electron we have that magnetic lorentz isn't insignifiant because :
$$ v \wedge B = \frac{\sigma^2 E^2}{ne}\mu_0 r  $$
So we would have a force that concentrate electron in the conductor but we always says that in DC we have an equal distribution in the conductor. So where is my mistake or my confusion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Lorentz force $\rho({\bf v}\times {\bf B})$ is cancelled by a radial ${\bf E}$ field that occurs because of the Coulomb force between the  conduction elecrons  and the positive ions enforces charge neutrality. The charge density does change by a tiny amount to set up this field. It's a kind of radial Hall effect.

Comment: Okay thank you ! and this effect doesn't happend at high frequency when dealing with AC current ? like there is a threshold where it can't be countered ?

Comment: At high frequency you have the skin effect. A different thing entirely.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect